# Как точно убедиться, что скрипт подключен?

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт, который подтягивает скрипты приложения с сервера и после их загрузки инициализирует приложение. На данный момент использую евент load, чтобы проверить подключился ли скрипт, но бывают случаи, когда старт приложения начинается раньше, чем скрипты подгрузились и соответствено вылезает еррор о несуществующей функции. Вопрос в том, как точно убедиться, что скрипты подключены?

```
!function(scripts){
  var counter = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++){
    var el = document.createElement("script");
    el.src = URL+"js/"+scripts[i]+".js";
    el.addEventListener('load', function() {
      counter +=1;
      if(counter === scripts.length) InitApp();
    });
    var el2 = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    el2.parentNode.insertBefore(el, el2.nextSibling);
  }
}(['script1', 'script1']);



function InitApp() {
    Aplication.createApp('root');
}
```

Comment: У вас там два одинаковых скрипта, так и должно быть?) `['script1', 'script1']`

Comment: Это пример. ......

Comment: Пишешь на необходимые строки: `console.log('connected');`

Comment: Уточните тогда, что за случаи, когда запуск начинается до загрузки. По идее, если у вас одна точка входа в приложение, то ошибок быть не должно.

Comment: Может ли быть такое что среди подключаемых скриптов есть зависимость и зависимый скрипт загружается быстрее основного?

Comment: Рандомно при загрузке странице, какой-то определенной последовательности неправильной загрузки не наблюдал.
Имеет место быть вариант frozencoasta, проверю сегодня